# How do you handle 3rd party(Guzzle) namespace conflicts in modules?

Tags: magento2.4, guzzle

I am implementing a payment method module, for a payment provider company.

That company has a proprietary php-sdk for all the actions around the payment requests. That sdk uses `guzzlehttp/guzzle`.

I have required the sdk in the magento module, which in turns has `guzzle` as its own dependency and so it requires that and everything else.

Now when I run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` I get the error that `ClientTrait` is already declared, because I found Guzzle being installed already in the Magento core.

The solution seems to be [php-scoper](https://github.com/humbug/php-scoper) but I failed to make it work and also failed to find any help online or examples of other modules who have done this.

The steps I have taken are:

- Install `php-scoper`
- Run `php-scoper add-prefix --prefix=[our unique prefix] vendor/
- Run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- Encounter error: `Interface "[Our Prefix]\GuzzleHttp\BodySummarizerInterface" not found`

The interface is there:

`/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/BodySummarizerInterface.php`:

```
<?php

namespace [Prefix]\GuzzleHttp;

use [Prefix]\Psr\Http\Message\MessageInterface;
/** @internal */
interface BodySummarizerInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns a summarized message body.
     */
    public function summarize(MessageInterface $message) : ?string;
}
```

So my question is, what are the steps I need to follow in order to load the sdk that already contains the Guzzle client and is currently conflicting with another Guzzle installation?